# rror: SecurityError: Request method not allowed - XMLHTTPRequest - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, xml, cors

I am attempting to do a get request and setup a new request header using the XMLHTTPRequest, however i continue to receive a 405 error. It probably CORS, but i have tried a lot of stuff with no luck.

Error: SecurityError: Request method not allowed
I am using the NPM package [XMLHTTPRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)

```
My get request:
const cjURL = 'https:URL';
const cjKey = 'Key'

let header = new Headers();
let xmlRHeader = new  XMLHttpRequest();
xmlRHeader.open().setRequestHeader('authorization', 'value');
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
header.set('autorization', `${this.cjKey}`);
let req = new Request(cjURL, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: header,
  mode: 'cors'

});


fetch(req)
.then ( (response) => {
  if(response !== null){
    return response;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Bad HTTP Request');
  }
})
.then ( (jsonData) => {
  console.log(jsonData);
})
.catch ((err) => {
  console.log('error', err.message);
});
```

Comment: Why are you setting `header.append('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');`? You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: "I am using the NPM package XMLHTTPRequest" — Then it is unlikely to be CORS because you are not using a browser.

Comment: Why do you start using `XMLHttpRequest` and then give up and switch to `fetch`? Where do these even come from, browsers supply them, but Node.js doesn't.

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:api]? The tag says "DO NOT USE"!

Comment: Yea i just starting using XMLHTTPRequest as of right now. I removed the API, didn't see that when i added it. I was more concerned with getting an answer lol. I will try to use the XMLHTTPRequest. Apparently the webservice i am using has an old style XML to provide. I have an Angular 6 front end with a Node JS backend. Just trying to get past CORS and get the data to display in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the request i needed back without worrying about CORS. In order to do this i used the following code:

const cjURL = 'The URL of the web service'

xhr is the variable assigned to the XMLHTTPRequest(). 
You must use the open then specify the method. In this case i need the GET method. 
If you set the method as true after, then it will make it async.

Next, Since my Web Service required that i specify a REQUEST header. I added a request header with setHRequestHeader. Note: You can only set a request header after the OPEN and before the SEND.

Then i want to check each status of my request from 1-4 to check the return of each state. [View all Ready States Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)

For more documentation on this check out this [documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', cjURL, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', cjKey)

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
  } else if (this.readyState == 3){
    console.log('3')
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  } else if (this.readyState == 2){
    console.log('2')
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  } else if (this.readyState == 1){
    console.log('1')
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  } 
}

xhr.send();
```